# Radio Button Value display on another form

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing issue to transfer checked radio button value from one form to another

My code in below

```
    <html>

<body>
<form id-"from1">
<input name="gender[]" id="gender[]" type="radio" value="male" checked>
<input name="gender[]" id="gender[]" type="radio" value="female" >

<input type="button" border="2" onClick="checkedRadio();" >
</form>

<form id="form2">

<p id="view" id="view">Display Here</p>

</form>
<script>

    function checkedRadio() {

        var input = document.getElementById("gender[]").value;
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = input;


    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

`
and I'm getting results as "male" always. please any one can help me on this issue, and it is preferred to get result as  instead of

Comment: You have the same `id` for both inputs.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: I need with same id to send these value as mail

Comment: The `name` is sent in a form POST/GET, not the id. You don't "need" the ids to be the same, because that is not allowed in the HTML standard.

Comment: assist me to use "document.getElementsByName" the result is "undefined"

Comment: That returns an array. You would need to loop through it and get the value of the selected. https://jsfiddle.net/m9u2vwv1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of all radios. You need to use querySelector and query it by name, but not id. Here's your fixed code

```
<html>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<input name="gender" id="genderMale" type="radio" value="male" checked>
<input name="gender" id="genderFemale" type="radio" value="female">

<input type="button" border="2" onClick="checkedRadio();" >
</form>

<form id="form2">

<p id="view" id="view">Display Here</p>

</form>
<script>

    function checkedRadio() {
        var input = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = input;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me required to send <p> value as email from "form 2" is it possible to convert into <input type="text">

Comment: Yes, i think so, just don't change the name

Comment: its not submitting with <p>, I belive it should be <input>, any suggestion

Comment: Oh, now i understand. You can just get innerHTML of p `document.getElementById("your_p_id").innerHTML;`

Comment: it works with "document.getElementById("your_p_id").value;" Thanks everyone for your support